# Google Script GET request issue

Tags: javascript, rest, google-apps-script, get

I'm trying to get a Google script (on a Google Sheet) to retrieve data from Float API. The endpoint and key are fine (tested and all works as expected on Postman) but it keeps returning 401.

Below is my code:

```
var API_KEY = "{ENTER YOUR KEY HERE}";
var ENDPOINT_PROJECTS = "https://api.float.com/api/v1/projects";

function getProjects() {

  var headers = {
    "Authorization" : "Bearer " + API_KEY,
  };

  var requestData = {
    "method" : "GET",
    "headers": headers,
    "muteHttpExceptions": false
  };

  // Get the data
  var fetchResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(ENDPOINT_PROJECTS);
  var responseCode = fetchResponse.getResponseCode();
  if (responseCode == "200") {
    var result = JSON.parse(fetchResponse.getContentText());
  } else {
    ui.alert("Error when attempting to fetch the list of spaces.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay looked like I completely missed a small yet very important part...even though I created an object to hold the method and headers I was not passing this into the actual fetch!!! (This is what happens when you attempt to do a *quick* script at the end of the day)

So instead of this

```
var fetchResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(ENDPOINT_PROJECTS);
```

we have this:

```
var fetchResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(ENDPOINT_PROJECTS, requestData);
```